# ImportError: cannot import name IPossibleSitenterfaces import IPossibleSite: version mismatch?

Tags: python, plone, zope

learner alert

FreeBSD 9.0

This worked first time:

http://plone.org/documentation/manual/installing-plone/installation-quick-guide

But following "Professional Plone 4 Development", failing to get a virtualenv working

in my virtualenv dir plonedev :

```
bin/instance fg

2012-07-18 09:04:58 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Wed Jul 18 09:04:58 2012
        Hostname: 0.0.0.0
        Port: 8080

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in <module>
    run()

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 22, in run
    starter.prepare()

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 86, in prepare
    self.startZope()

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 259, in startZope
    Zope2.startup()

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Zope2/__init__.py", line 46, in startup
    from Zope2.App.startup import startup as _startup

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 38, in <module>
    import OFS.Application

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 22, in <module>
    import App.Product

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/App/Product.py", line 44, in <module>
    from OFS.Folder import Folder

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/OFS/Folder.py", line 24, in <module>
    from webdav.Collection import Collection

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/webdav/Collection.py", line 30, in <module>
    from webdav.Resource import Resource

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/webdav/Resource.py", line 35, in <module>
    from OFS.event import ObjectClonedEvent

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/OFS/event.py", line 20, in <module>
    import OFS.interfaces

  File "/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/OFS/interfaces.py", line 19, in <module>
    from zope.location.interfaces import IPossibleSite

ImportError: cannot import name IPossibleSitenterfaces import IPossibleSite
```

I egrepped the plonedev tree and found in `/usr/home/mydir/plonedev/eggs/zope.location-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO`:

```
    4.0.0 (2012-06-07)
    ------------------

    - Removed backward-compatibility imports:

      - ``zope.copy.clone`` (aliased as ``zope.location.pickling.locationCopy``)

      - ``zope.copy.CopyPersistent`` (aliased as
        ``zope.location.pickling.CopyPersistent``).

      - ``zope.site.interfaces.IPossibleSite`` (aliased as
        ``zope.location.interfaces.IPossibleSite``).
```

Looks like I've got some version mismatch, but not sure how it got there nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You need an older version of zope.location: 3.9.1.

Most Plone users use buildout to handle getting a zope instance with the correct versions set up. I would expect Professional Plone 4 Development to recommend that as well.

If you want to handle it manually in a virtualenv, you need to look at the KGS (Known Good Set) of packages, which buildout also does. For Zope2 2.13.15 it is here:
http://download.zope.org/Zope2/index/2.13.15/versions.cfg

zope.location itself is not in there, but at the top it says:

extends = http://download.zope.org/zopetoolkit/index/1.0.7/ztk-versions.cfg

If you look in that file, you will see zope.location 3.9.1.

Comment: thank!  the shovel works great, I'm in deeper.  :)

with that versions.cfg:

python bootstrap.py --distribute
  File "bootstrap.py", line 2
    extends = http://download.zope.org/zopetoolkit/index/1.0.7/ztk-versions.cfg
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: From the original question it looked like you were not using buildout but using a virtualenv. Now with the bootstrap.py it looks like you are using buildout after all. I'd recommend just using the Unified Installer and the quick guide you pointed to earlier. Can you try to explain again what you are doing? Maybe edit the original question and put that SyntaxError in there. Error tracebacks in comments here on stackoverflow are not very readable, unfortunately.